# How to write a script in c shell so that doing a `cd` will automatically fire a `ll` or a `ls` as well

Tags: linux, unix, csh

It is really cubersome to change directories using `cd` and the again do an `ls` or an `ll`. I noticed that more than 80 % of the times, I am always doing a `ll` after my `cd`. So my question is how to write a `c shell` script to do this. 
Whenever a cd is done, can the `c shell` be commanded to also do a `ll` automatically ?

Comment: Don't forget to read http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/ and switch to a better shell, like `zsh` or `bash`  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a script, just make a simple alias definition:

- bash notation: `alias cd="cd $1; ll "`
- csh notation: `alias cd cd \!:1\; ll`

Note the leading space (" ") in the bash version, it prevents the result to be alias expanded again. So it prevents loops.

Comment: I just realize myself that this does not seem to work when using a csh (I use the normal bash). But since csh knows `alias` as well I assume this is just a question of the `$1`. What is the correct csh expression?

Comment: it is supposed to be $1 in csh also

Comment: Ok, tried around a while, I added a 'csh notation' to the answer which works for me using csh.

Comment: That's still not right for the `csh` notation.  If you do just a `cd`, you'll get a "bad ! arg selector' since you're requiring at least one parameter.  The correct alias is `alias cd 'cd \!* ; ll'`  And if you use `tcsh`, you can set the **cwdcmd** alias to command(s) you want executed after changing directories.

Comment: For me my solution I posted did work when using a csh. But you certainly know better.

Comment: alias cd 'cd \!* ; ll' is correct for tcsh I can confirm.

Comment: Oh, ok, that explains: csh and tcsh are something different. In the question you mentioned csh, not tcsh...